# Phoenix Link method: :delete doesn't work in Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework

in my phoenix app, a <%= link ... , ,method: :delete %> in Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <%= if !@conn.assigns.current_user do %>
      <li> <%= link "Log In" , to: session_path(@conn, :new) %></li>
    <% else %>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Hi!, <%= @conn.assigns.current_user.username %>
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link "Log out", to: session_path(@conn, :delete, @conn.assigns.current_user), method: "delete" %></li>
          <li> <%= link "Log In" , to: session_path(@conn, :new) %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

but when i make it outside the "dropdown-menu", it works just fine.

when i change <%= link ...%> to <%= button... %>, it works fine as well!!


My brunch.js has include sass in plugin

```
plugins: {
  babel: {
    // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
    ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
  },

  sass: {
    options: {
      includePaths: ["node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets"], // tell sass-brunch where to look for files to @import
      // minimum precision required by bootstrap-sass
      //precision: 8
    },
    precision: 8
  },
  copycat: {
    "fonts": ["node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap"]   // copy node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/* to priv/static/fonts/
  }
},

...
...

npm: {
  enabled: true,
  whitelist: ["phoenix", "phoenix_html", "jquery"],
  globals: { // bootstrap-sass' JavaScript requires both '$' and 'jQuery' in global scope
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap-sass' // require bootstrap-sass' JavaScript globally
  }
}
```

I think the problem is related to javascript, but i don't know how to fix it.

Does someone has the same problem? thanks!

Comment: By "doesn't work" you mean nothing happens if you click it? or it isn't styled properly? or you can't see anything? or something else?

Comment: it did nothing. and the url will be appended a "#" at the end

Comment: Are you including `phoenix_html` correctly? In a new project, the brunch config has this: `javascripts: { joinTo: "js/app.js" }` and in `app.js` it has `import "phoenix_html"` and `link method: :delete` works with this. Can you also check if the generated `priv/static/js/app.js` includes `phoenix_html`?

Comment: @Dogbert yes, brunch.js has ```javascripts: { ... }``` , and app.js includes ```phoenix_html```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem comes from Bootstrap's JavaScript part.

Here's the offending line in `bootstrap.js` (line 910 on v3.3.7):

```
.on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
```

To make your links work, you either have to not wrap your links in `<form>` tags or you remove this event handler, by including the following code in your `app.js`:

```
$(document).off('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form');
```